# Widget should show or hide based on option chosen in drop down menu

Tags: ruby, qt, methods, qtruby

I have a dropdown menu with around 5-6 items in it.

I want other widgets to appear in the same window when I select the particular  option in the ComboBox. For example: when I chose "1-Standard" in the ComboBox, the widget defined in `acc_ui` has to pop up and so on.

This is the code I tried:

```
require 'Qt'
class Auth < Qt::Widget

  slots 'slotFunctionChanged(int)'

  def initialize(parent=nil)
    super(parent)
    setWindowTitle("Action");
    setFixedSize 750,530

    function_ui

    show   
  end

  def function_ui
    @funLabel = Qt::Label.new "Func: ", self 
    @funLabel.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 14)
    combo = Qt::ComboBox.new self 
    combo.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 12 )
    combo.addItem "1- Standard"
    combo.addItem "2- Custom"
    combo.addItem "3- Non-custom"
    combo.addItem "4- Non-Standard"
    combo.addItem "5- Plastic"

    connect combo, SIGNAL('activated(int)'), self, SLOT('slotFunctionChanged(int)')
    combo.resize 170,20
    combo.move 170,100
    @funLabel.move 95,100

  end 

  def slotFunctionChanged(index)
    case index 
    when 0 
      acc_ui()
    when 1 
      store_ui()     
    end 
  end 

  def acc_ui 
    @accLineedit = Qt::Lineedit.new(self)
    @accLineedit.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 12)
    @accLabel = Qt::Label.new "Acc: ", self 
    @accLabel.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 14)
    @accLabel.move 95,185
    @accLineedit.resize 170,20
    @accLineedit.move 170,185
  end 

  def store_ui
    @storeLineedit = Qt::Lineedit.new(self)
    @storeLineedit.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 12)
    @storeLabel = Qt::Label.new "Store: ", self 
    @storeLabel.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times New Roman", 14)
    @storeLabel.move 120,210
    @storeLineedit.resize 140,20
    @storeLineedit.move 170,210

  end 

end 

app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
widget = Auth.new
widget.show
app.exec
```

Comment: What is the problem? We need a description of what it's not doing correctly. Please read "[ask]". Also, is this the bare minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem? If not, reduce it. Lots of code slows our ability to help you, and takes away our time for helping others. [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for that. This was the first time i was posting , will keep that in mind from next time. 

My problem here was : Inside case statement, when i try to call a method which i have defined separately , it is not getting invoked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- move all code from  `acc_ui` and from `store_ui` to `function_ui`
- in `function_ui`: apply the `show` method to all widgets that should be shown by default, and the `hide` method to all widgets that should be hidden by default
- in `acc_ui` and `store_ui`: only use `show` and `hide` methods to let the widgets appear and disappear as you wish

Comment: If i want to show storeLabel widget, how do i show it ? 

show and hide methods does not seem to be working with this

Comment: `@storeLabel.show` should do. If not, you might want to upload your last code to https://gist.github.com/ and share the link. I'll be happy to check there and help you to get it running.

Comment: Thanks. The above way of show and hide did work for me. However, I am not getting how to set the default appearance before individual cases would be dealt with.

Comment: GUI is working fine. But it seems to freeze for some reason after few minutes on a particular screen. Any thoughts on what may be the reason ?

Comment: How can one tell without seeing the code? As already offered: put in on http://gist.github.com if you like, and I'll have a look.

Comment: In case the answer was useful for you, feel free to both, upvote and accept.

Comment: Thanks wil upload the code in that link.
And I have upvoted as well, however it would be taken into account only after I reach the minimum reputation as I joined the forum recently .